# Decryption of REST API response

Tags: java, encryption

To decrypt an AES encrypted field through REST API, i've have one issue in understanding the IV(Initialization Vector) and how to use that to decrypt the first block of 16 characters.

Encrypted field from the REST response JSON (description form field):

> "description":"84d1d37bdb7a3200750573ffbf96191f:0aZdRxsIqSpFtuszNr73na/J9JuMLNB>0J6T2f2FrV0sUlMmbW4prbZMmXGnLU4W6CDlb5F1lb8js\r\nRHw6tfyZd5ZL//ZUlozE916wvP+zd+>uUfjpk2Bl9o2uAu+1bsNoAVdtP5m5fbnkjxf9yLRzREVVO\r\nIwYQOxNI/CeX2dzF/Uc="

I was able to identify this

> "0aZdRxsIqSpFtuszNr73na/J9JuMLNB>0J6T2f2FrV0sUlMmbW4prbZMmXGnLU4W6CDlb5F1lb8js>r\nRHw6tfyZd5ZL//ZUlozE916wvP+zd+>uUfjpk2Bl9o2uAu+1bsNoAVdtP5m5fbnkjxf9yLRzREVV>O\r\nIwYQOxNI/CeX2dzF/Uc="

as the actual description and,

> "84d1d37bdb7a3200750573ffbf96191f"

to be somehow related to my question in this post.

**Encryption method:** AES 128 Bit.

**Password:** 1234567890123456

**Original Text:** “new description for new incident.

www.google.com

lets see if the initial part is same or it changes for this new incident”

**Decrypted output:** “bGOn>22H~KH:38/_for new incident.

www.google.com

lets see if the initial part is same or it changes for this new incident”

**Decryption Used:** AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

How to decrypt the first block which is jumbled in the Decrypted output. In other words, how to interpret **84d1d37bdb7a3200750573ffbf96191f** in terms of IV to decrypt the first 16 characters ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the Java code:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class AESDecryption {
private static String key = "1234567890123456";
private static String encryptedStr = "0aZdRxsIqSpFtuszNr73na/J9JuMLNB0J6T2f2FrV0sUlMmbW4prbZMmXGnLU4W6CDlb5F1lb8js\r\nRHw6tfyZd5ZL//ZUlozE916wvP+zd+uUfjpk2Bl9o2uAu+1bsNoAVdtP5m5fbnkjxf9yLRzREVVO\r\nIwYQOxNI/CeX2dzF/Uc=";
private static String padding = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private static int iterationCount = 65536;
private static int keyLength = 128;
private static String secretKeyAlg = "PBEWithHmacSHA1AndAES_128";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String finalStrDec = null;
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(secretKeyAlg);
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), generateSalt(), iterationCount, keyLength);
    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);
    Cipher cipherDec = Cipher.getInstance(padding);
    cipherDec.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivSpec);
    byte[] original = cipherDec.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedStr));
    finalStrDec = new String(original);
    System.out.println(finalStrDec);
}

public static byte[] generateSalt() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
    random.nextBytes(bytes);
    String salt = new String(bytes);
    return salt.getBytes("UTF-8");
}
}
```

Comment: You will have to use the same IV which you used for encryption for decryption as well.

Comment: I don't see your encryption code. Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: The encryption was done in ServiceNow. I used REST API to get a json response from a servicenow incident. The data you see here is a particular key - value pair from the json. I've added Encryption method: AES 128 Bit.

Password: 1234567890123456 this was used by servicenow to encrypt